# date manipulation in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

lets say I have a table with three datetime columnns

posted_at,
date_start,
date_end

posted_at is a timestamp for when the record is created. The problem is that due to a bug in our system, date_start and date_end are one month ahead. is it possible to write a sql query that looks for all records where the posted_at is before a certain date and set the dat_start and date_end back a month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0a9f5/1

```
update dates
set date_start = date_start - interval '1 month'
, date_end = date_end  - interval '1 month'
where posted_at < '2014-01-01';
```

Useful info on Postgres date functions can be found here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL#I.27m_porting_an_app_from_MS_SQL_Server.2C_and_I_need_to_support_the_DATEDIFF_and_DATEADD_functions_so_that_my_stored_views_will_work